# What does the instruction mrc p15 do in ARM inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

What does this line in ARM assembly do?

```
mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : : "r" (counter)
```

What is `p15`?  Usually registers are prefixed with `r` such as in `r15`.

What is the symbol `::` and what are the roles or `c9, c1`?

Comment: This is gcc-style inline assembly - you should post the surrounding code too if you want a complete explanation.

Comment: [How read coprocessor registers in ARM architecture](//stackoverflow.com/q/49051641) shows some example surrounding code for an `mrc p15` instruction.  (Except it's writing a GPR instead of reading one)  Also related: [System Control Registers in ARM Cortex-A7](//stackoverflow.com/q/33515477) about `mrc` and `mcr`.

Comment: The `" : : "r" (counter)` is specifically part of the immediately preceding code, which would have been `asm volatile("`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst `MRC` is a generic co-processor inter-op instruction,  `cp15` is the *control processor* - which all modern ARM CPUs have and this has been used by ARM as a means of extending the instruction set for on-chip units such as the cache, MMU, performance monitoring and lots else besides.

Taking your instruction a bit at a time:

```
mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : : "r" (counter)
```

According to the [ARM Cortex A7 MPCore Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464d/DDI0464D_cortex_a7_mpcore_r0p3_trm.pdf) the instruction format is:

```
MRC{cond} P15, <Opcode_1>, <Rd>, <CRn>, <CRm>, <Opcode_2>
```

And on pages 4-11 this is described as a transfer of a CPU register to the performance monitor count register (I guess `count=0` and this is a reset of the performance counter).

As for the syntax of inline assembler. refer to [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.1) for a x86 overview - which is probably similar to ARM.

The `: : "r" (counter)`  means that the instruction has:

- No output in a register that needs to end up in a local variable
- Takes input from variable `counter`, and the register this is in should be used as `%0`.
- There are no side effects the compiler ought to be aware of (clobbers)

Comment: What  `<Rd>, <CRn>, <CRm>` stand for ?

Comment: @0x90 As per ARM's standard notation for their documentation, `Rd` is a placeholder for the destination (a GPR, so it makes sense to expand `%0` at that position, the register picked by the compiler).  `Rn` and `Rm` are source operands.  In this case `CRn` not just `Rn`, because `CRn` and `CRm` are "coprocessor" registers, not general-purpose R0-R15.

Answer (score 1):

The coprocessors in the arm are more obvious/visible perhaps than other processors.  Nevertheless this is a coprocessor access function, the coprocessor interface is generic these instructions are generic as if you are just filling in items on a generic bus.  Now arm does re-use things in that a coprocessor register in one core if present in another is more likely than not to be related or the same.  The right answer is to go to the arm website (infocenter.arm.com) and find both the arm arm (arm architectural reference manual) and trm (technical reference manual) for the family and core of processor you are using or looking at code for, in one or both manuals it will have a section on coprocessors and as you push into that section you will see the coprocessor number then register within that coprocessor and some of the numbers will make sense.  ARM generally will say, to read this register here is the exact instruction, to write this register here is the exact instruction, and it will take the form as you have presented it.  If you are looking to go backwards from code to what it does you will see that you can very quickly work your way into that section of the manual and quickly find the instruction then see what it does for that particular core or family.  The other way around is to look at chapter and section titles finding the register of interest then the syntax for the instruction used to manipulate it.

As far as the : : double colons, I am guessing you took this from inline assembly and that is related to inline assembly, a compiler thing and is not related at all to the arm instruction, the arm instruction ends with the c13, 0.