# Can someone explain the power control register in exynos ARM?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

In the Linux kernel, more accurately [/arch/arm/mach-exynos/cpuidle.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-exynos/cpuidle.c#72) on 3.9-rc6, the lines reads

```
static unsigned int g_pwr_ctrl, g_diag_reg;

static void save_cpu_arch_register(void)
{
    /*read power control register*/
    asm("mrc p15, 0, %0, c15, c0, 0" : "=r"(g_pwr_ctrl) : : "cc");
    /*read diagnostic register*/
    asm("mrc p15, 0, %0, c15, c0, 1" : "=r"(g_diag_reg) : : "cc");
    return;
}
```

After researching the issue, this appears to be *gcc inline* assembly. Considering it's a critical component, the `asm` is reading this as it's either

1. Faster, and therefore more efficient
2. Not available in C

I checked the [ARM Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihfifej.html) for `MCR` as I'm learning assembly, but I could tell `MCR` was a Coprocessor due to its three letter length. The inline asm appears to access the [power control register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihfifej.html) and save the result (from the register) into an unsigned integer in the first line (to be called up at some point, I expect).

In regards to the power control register, the arm manual lists,

- the clock latency for your implementation of the Cortex-A9 processor
- dynamic clock gating.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is needed at-all, this can be accessed on the fly, in a function.

Lastly, the ARM Manual lists the design of the 32bit wide register. The base-clock appears to be set there, are we reading this while starting up from an idle context process?

I have also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179872/what-does-the-given-line-do-in-arm-assembly-and-what-is-the-purpose-of-each-vari) - this may also help you.

Comment: @dwelch I cannot understand why you're asking me this. The code is not mine, it's from the Linux kernel (as I said in the first line). My research was plentiful; 4 links, and one stackoverflow link, plus my own knowledge - That's as far as I could go without help.

Comment: Inline assembler is often used when you cant do it in C directly, those instructions must be used and as a result you cant get a generic C compiler to generate them.  so you must use inline assembler.  Inline assembler is very specific to a compiler, it is not universal or portable.  So that is one answer, to one question, the next is go read the gcc documentation or the other so answers to find out about inline assembler details, these are generic not specific to one instruction set.  What the hardware is doing is the only valid so question here, and what is it that you didnt understand?

Comment: @dwelch I have edited to the title to reflect my concerns. I needed more information on the power control register. That was the focus of my question - if you'd like to answer it, go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question does lack focus, please consider updating it.  I will assume that you are trying to understand the **exynos** suspend/resume mechanism in the Linux kernel.

### Why Inline assembler

> ... this appears to be **gcc inline** assembly. Considering it's a critical component, the asm is reading this as it's either
>   a) faster, and therefore more efficient;
>   b) not available in C

We choose option **b**, there is no way to express `mcr`/`mrc` in *C*.

### Inline clobber list

> Secondly, ... `: : "cc");`

This is a `gcc` clobber list.  It says that the *condition codes* will be altered by the instruction.  This maybe just to ensure that `gcc` decides not to discard this instruction.  You can read more in [the gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

### What is this doing

> I'm having trouble understanding why this is needed at-all, this can be accessed on the fly, in a function.

The portion you need to look at is `exynos4_enter_core0_aftr()`.  This uses both `save_cpu_arch_register()` and `restore_cpu_arch_register()`.  So, there is a dual set of functions and we note that the values are stored in *globals*.  The other thing to note is the `cpu_suspend(0, idle_finisher);`. This function tells Linux the **cpu** is suspended and then calls `cpu_do_idle();` which is usually an ARM [**WFI**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0311d/Chdggbei.html) ([wait for interrupt](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/CHDEEIJB.html)) instruction.  This makes the CPU **freeze** at that instruction until an enabled interrupt triggers.  The issue with suspending a CPU clock at full speed, is this can waste some current/power.  Typically,  SDRAM and platform clocks maybe automatically put to in low power states in this mode.

You will have to consult the data sheets on your CPU/SOC for more.  However, back to the question.  It is most likely that this low power mode destroys/alters these co-processor registers, so `save_cpu_arch_register()` and `restore_cpu_arch_register()` are needed to ensure they remain as they were before the call.  The code could probably use locals in `exynos4_enter_core0_aftr()`.  They do need to be saved and restored or the CPU may resume with weird power/voltage/clocks.  It could also be that `cpu_do_idle()` is over-ridden for your machine and it is altering these registers.

So briefly, this function is to save some state that will be destroyed when the CPU goes to **suspend** or *wait for interrupt* mode.